# Правильное развёртывание веб приложения

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, war

При развёртывании веб приложения работающего с бд правильно сделать инициализацию (создание, схемы, таблиц, заполнения) в самом приложении или делать это руками или через скрипт на сервере?

Comment: в системе миграций. схема и сиды.

Answer (score 2):

Через систему миграций - тулзу, предназначенную для изменения структуры базы данных. Самые популярные для Java - это [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) и [Flyweight](https://flywaydb.org) (хотя второй нельзя полноценно назвать системой миграций).

Заполнение базы данных нужно делать через отдельную систему (т.н. seed), однако я не встречал подобных утилит для java.

Если вы будете делать это все руками, то рано или поздно столкнетесь с тем, что версии базы данных в разработке и продакшене не соответствуют друг другу, а найти различие будет не так уж и просто.

Answer (score -1):

Заполнять таблицы можно и так и так, не принципиально. А вот создание структруры таблиц в БД лучше всё таки сделать вручную. Как по мне так намного быстрее и проще решать возникающие попутно траблы